# Android which layout should i use

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in andorid. I want to create a layout like this:-

[image]

When  i rotate my android device then it should look like this:-

[image]

There must be some padding between these images. Please suggest me how can i implement this. Which type of layout i should use for this.
I am waiting for your suggestions. You may send me some links related to this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GridLayout`. This will work fine for orientation change easily. Here I have posted a [sample code](http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/custom-grid-view-in-android/).

*You need to remove codes for Text.*

[Download images](http://developer.android.com/shareables/sample_images.zip) which used in this example.

Answer (score 2):

[GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

You can find nice tutorials about different layout [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/series/android-user-interface-design/)

Answer (score 1):

Use GridLayout OR TableLayout but you have to write Condition For Displaying images according to orientation

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code might help you:

```
    <TableLayout 
 android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_marginTop="10dip">

     <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:padding="10dip">
         <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
         android:text="@string/name"
         android:textColor="@color/black" 
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:paddingRight="5dip"
         android:layout_weight=".30"
         android:width="0dip"></TextView>

          <TextView android:id="@+id/name_value" 
         android:text="AAA"
         android:textColor="@color/black" 
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:paddingLeft="5dip" 
         android:singleLine="false"
         android:layout_weight=".70"
         android:width="0dip"></TextView>

     </TableRow>
```

With this way, you can control any dp of padding or margin wherever you want. on Screen orientation change you can control the layouts.
You can change:

```
    android:layout_weight=".30"
```

to control the widths of each column.

This is a working code.